# TeamCity self extracting zip as artifact

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, winzip

Is it possible to have teamcity generate a self-extracting zip file as the artifact of a build?

Can I create a build step that calls winzip and winzip self-extractor or can I somehow create a linked build that does this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Build steps can run any command-line functions, including scripts and programs. Depending on how involved creating the archive is, you may want to write a simple shell script (or batch, as the case may be) that copies the files, creates the SFX archive, and then copies that to a known location. Then, in Teamcity's artifact filters, add the archive as an artifact and it will be published with builds.

You can also tweak the build step to only create the archive after the rest of the build succeeds, or provide arguments to the archival script (or have the script notify Teamcity, check the message-passing documents for how to handle that).